# deserialize data from stringify data

Tags: string, deserialize, serialize

I have read many posts regarding this but I m not able to to deserialize the data . So please can anyone help me with it.
 serialized data:

"fieldlist" : JSON.stringify(selfield)

but I m not able to deserilaize it and also store it to list.

/*Apex class:*/

```
 String lststr;
 lststr=(string)JSON.deserialize(fieldlist,String.class);
 System.debug('lststr'+lststr);
 List<String> lstAlpha = fieldlist.split(',');
 System.debug('lstAlpha'+lstAlpha);
```

This is the code I am trying but there is no value coming in lststr

fieldlist["name","isdeleted"]

This is the form of my fieldlist value
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: For this to work your input JSON must be of the form (including quotes) "a, b, c". If the quotes are missing (these can be single or double quotes) then it isn't a JSON string and won't parse into a string. Additionally, you then split the "fieldlist" by commas, rather than using the lststr. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/282264/edit) your question to include things like what the fieldlist value looks like.

Comment: fieldlist["name","isdeleted"] in this form I m getting my data in fieldlist

Comment: what type of data is  coming if you put debug log like `system.debug('before:'+fieldlist);`

Comment: same data is coming and after deserialize it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
String fieldlist = '["name","isdeleted"]';

String[] lststr;

lststr=(string[])JSON.deserialize(fieldlist,List<String>.class);

System.debug('lststr'+lststr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much